# How configure Nhibernate to not save object in current session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have three entites: Users, Roles and Permissions.
There two controllers: UserController and RolePermissionController. All controller wrapped by Nhibernate Session.

When I create fill Role Permissions, User doesn't exist. So I storage my new Permission object in the ASP.MVC session. I wants to save new Role with permission when I`ll create User in the UserController.

But when I filled new Role with exist Permission (I got then from DB by Nhibernate) and went to the User Controller New object Role created, without call Session.SaveOrUpdate or any other methods.

I tried to use Evict after fill my new role with exist permissions:

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISession>().Evict(newRole);
```

But it didn't help.
So I want to say to Nhibernate - don't save entity on this transaction (RolePermissionController) - and save as connected to User object entities in the UserController.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a cascade from Permission to Role set up in your mappings.

Comment: I don`t think so. The problem in the Nhibernate session, not in the cascade.

Comment: are you sure the session object you are calling Evict() on is the same one used in RolePermissionController? I would use .GetHashCode() to be sure it's the same object.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but it still might be a solution - how about collecting all the information through a ViewModel, so that you end up with a single controller action that takes the information from the ViewModel, creates the Role and the User at the same time (i.e. during the same request), and no need for messy session stuff.

Maybe not the answer you were looking for, but I've done something similar this way, and it works just fine.